# PowerMockito mocking a method call

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

I want to test method A, inside there is a call to method B, both in the same class, inside method B are calls to other methods from other classes. I want to mock method B call, but Mockito also executes the inside of method B and gives a NPE.

I tried

```
PowerMockito.when(classA.methodB(arg1, arg2)).thenReturn(true);
```

But method B is still executed. How can I overcome this?

Example:

```
    protected boolean B(String arg1, String arg2){
        String newString = arg2+arg2;
        return methodFromAnotherClass(newString);
    }
    
    protected boolean A(Integer arg1, String arg2, Double arg3){
        //some code
        if(B(arg2, String.valueOf(arg1))}
            //some code
        else 
            //some code
    return true;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: I updated the initial question